# Concatenating Numpy array to Numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to make a for loop that each time adds an array, to the end of an array of arrays and I can't quite put my finger on how to. 
The general idea of the program:

```
for x in range(0,longnumber):
    generatenewarray
    add new array to end of array
```

So for example, the output of:

```
newArray = [1,2,3]
array  = [[1,2,3,4],[1,4,3]]
```

would be: `[[1,2,3,4],[1,4,3],[1,2,3]]`

If the wording is poor let me know and I can try and edit it to be better!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
list_of_arrays = []
for x in range(0,longnumber):
    a = generatenewarray
    list_of_arrays.append(a)
```

Comment: It's a numpy array and needs to return one, so apparend doesn't work I don't think.

Comment: well, your problem doesn't seem well-formed then, as your arrays have different dimensions, and the only way you could concatenate them would be to make a 1xN array, which I'm guessing is not what you want.  If your individual arrays actually are the same size, then try `numpy.vstack()` mentioned above.  `big_array = numpy.vstack( (big_array, new_array))`...note that growing arrays like this isn't exactly efficient...

Comment: Better to append to a list.  If it must be an array (object dtype), convert it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this will work. You turn both numpy arrays into lists, add those two lists, and finally convert the result into a new numpy array:

```
np.array(array.tolist() + newArray.tolist())
```